# Robocopy: is /MON:1 the same as /MOT:1?

Tags: robocopy

I'm new to Robocopy and I have the following simple script:

```
robocopy source dest /MON:1
```

But when I run it, the following options are applied:

> Options : *.* /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /MON:1 /MOT:1 /R:1000000 /W:30

The script checks for changes every minute (as per /MOT:1), but does not do anything when I add a file to the source until the next check.

It is my understanding that /MON:1 should copy across when it detects a single change, so why is /MOT:1 added automatically?

The only thing I can think of is that /MON:1 and /MOT:1 are functionally equivalent, I've looked around but can't see anywhere that confirms this.

Can someone shed some light on how /MON:1 works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my own testing,

`/MON:n` implies `/MOT:1` (it will check if n changes have been made every 1 minute)

also:

`/MOT:m` implies `/MON:1` (it will check every m minutes if any (n=1) changes have been made) (however, I don't know if there are any unforseen differences between actually adding the implied command or not...)